# Using SlickEdit to compile Arduino files

Tags: compiler

I would like to compile my Arduino sketches in SlickEdit.  I have turned on the verbose compile output in the standard IDE and I can see the compile and switches, but it doesn't appear that there is a Makefile in use.  I don't see the "Entering" and "Leaving" messages that I associate with Make anyway.  Is using a third party tool to control the build an Arduino no-no?  Has anyone used Make to build Arduino?

Comment: Can you elaborate please? What is SlickEdit? (link). *I don't see the "Entering" and "Leaving" messages that I associate with Make anyway.* - **make** doesn't have such messages per se. *Is using a third party tool to control the build an Arduino no-no?* - no, a lot of people do that.

Comment: Arduino doesn't use Make. In the settings there is an option to use an external editor. If you enable this you can write code in SlickEdit, but you'd have to use the Arduino IDE for compiling and uploading.

Comment: Try to see if you can live with using slickedit as the externally editor. I havent used slickedit as a project mgmt but have done so with si and pn. Both are fairly straight forward but thee setup process is fairly manual. On the automation from sublime text can be used as a full blown Arduino environment so you may check that out as a possible alternative.

Comment: Many people use Make to compile Arduino software - but the Arduino IDE doesn't. There are many projects online to implement the build procedure using Make. Try googling for them.

Comment: The first two lines of the arduino verbose output show you how to call the arduino builder api. It will then do the rest.

Comment: @VisualMicro, you should add this as the answer.  After creating two tools(one for each line) in SE, a dump-prefs and a Build, I get a binary.  Adding a third tool called Download, lets me perform all basic operations in SE that I do in the IDE.